# This is code for a form, which involves input validation. How do I make the JS code function properly?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, debugging

This is a website that uses form validation, if the input is valid, the button should not be disabled. If the input is invalid, the button should be disabled. Until I added the Validation code (JS commented), everything worked and the data was entered into the table, but post Validation, it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
          <head>
               <title>Table Append w/ User Input</title>
               <script lang="JavaScript">
                    function MainJS(){
                         const submit = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
                         const fullnameVal = document.getElementById('fullname');
                         const UIDVal = getElementById('userID');
                         const regVal = getElementById('regiment');
                         const RegForm = document.getElementById('RegisterForm');

                         fullnameVal.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                              isValidfullname = fullnameVal.checkValidity();
                              if (isValidfullname == true) {
                                   submit.disabled = false;
                              } else {
                                   submit.disabled = true;
                              }
                         });

                         UIDVal.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                              isValidUID = UIDVal.checkValidity();
                              if (isValidregiment||isValidfullname||isValidUID) {
                                   submit.disabled = false;
                              } else {
                                   submit.disabled = true;
                              }
                         });

                         regVal.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                              isValidregiment = regVal.checkValidity();
                              if (isValidregimentVal||isValidfullnameVal||isValidUIDVal){
                                   submit.disabled = false;
                              } else {
                                   submit.disabled = true;
                              }
                         });

                         submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
                              RegForm.submit();
                         });

                         function fillTable(){
                              var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                              var row = table.insertRow(1);
                              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                              var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
                              cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("userID").value;
                              cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
                              cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("rank").value;
                              cell4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("regiment").value;
                              cell5.innerHTML = document.getElementById("branch").value;
                              cell6.innerHTML = document.getElementById("reason").value;
                              return false;
                         }
                    }
               </script>
               <link href="stylesheetone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
          </head>
          <body style="background-color:#8ed2e8;color:#fff;" onload="MainJS()">
               <div id="P1">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center;" class="x">New Age Veteran Help Center</h2>
               </div>
               <h2>Who We Are: </h2>
               <p style="font-family:Arial;">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp We are New Age, and we want to create a better life for those who dedicated their lives to protecting our country.
               We have joined up with hundreds of companies across the nation to make <i>your</i> life better. sign up now for an entry to a better life.
               Submit your request, and within 72 hours, we will link you up with companies across the nation. <br><p style="font-family: Arial;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Welcome to a New Age.</p>
               </p>
               <p style="margin-top:75px;text-align:center;" >
                    <a href="#Form">Register Now!</a>
                    <a href="#Table">View Database</a>
               </p>
               <p class="spacer">p</p>
               <div id="Form">
                <form action="" onsubmit="return MainJS();" id="RegisterForm">
                    <p>User ID:</p><input type="text" id ="userID" pattern="[0-9]{2,6}" required/><br><br>
                    <p>Email:</p><input type="email" id ="fullname" required/><br><br>
                    <p>Regiment:</p><input type="text" id="regiment" pattern="[0-9]{1,3}" required/>
                    <p class="minispacer">p</p>
                    <p>Rank:
                         <select id="rank" required>
                              <option value="Private">Private</option>
                              <option value="Sergeant">Sergeant</option>
                              <option value="Major">Major</option>
                              <option value="General">General</option>
                         </select>
                    </p>
                    <p class="minispacer">p</p>
                    <p>Branch: 
                    <select id="branch" required>
                         <option value="">Your Branch: </option>
                         <option value="Army">Army</option>
                         <option value="Marines">Marines</option>
                         <option value="Air Force">Air Force</option>
                         <option value="Navy">Navy</option>
                         <option value="Coast Guard">Coast Guard</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <p>Why Are You Here?
                         <select id="reason">
                              <option value="">Why are You Here? </option>
                              <option value="Job Opportunities">Job Opportunities</option>
                              <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
                              <option value="Pastimes">Pastimes</option>
                              <option value="Housing">Housing</option>
                              <option value="Impairment">Impairment</option>
                         </select>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
               </form>
               </div>
               <a href="#Table">View The Output</a>
               <a href="#P1">Return To The Main Page</a>
               <p class="spacer">hello</p>
               <div id="Table">
               <table class="table" id = "myTable" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                    <tr>
                         <th>ID</th>
                         <th>Name</th>
                         <th>Rank</th>
                         <th>Regiment</th>
                         <th>Branch</th>
                         <th>Reason</th>
                    </tr>
               </table>
               </div>
               <div style="margin:100px;text-align: center;">
               <a href="#Form">Go Back</a>
               <br>
               <br>
               <br>
               <a href="#P1">Return To The Main Page</a>
               </div>
          </body>
```

`function fillTable()` is the functional JS.
All of the other JS in `MainJS()` is what is causing the problem.

Comment: `<script lang="JavaScript">` — The `lang` attribute describes the **human** language the element contains (e.g. `en` for English.) `lang="JavaScript"` is nonsense.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the "minimal") and a *clear problem statement*. "it is not working" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: @Quentin It might have been more helpful (and less agressive), instead of telling the OP he'd written "nonsense", to point out he was mistaking the `lang` attribute for the long-deprecated `language` attribute on `script` tags, or perhaps thinking of the also-now-unnecessary `type` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Found some errors in your code, they are

```
const UIDVal = getElementById('userID');
const regVal = getElementById('regiment');
```

You can't use `getElementById` by itself, it needs to be called as a method of an element, such as `document` or some other js element. So it should be changed to

```
const UIDVal = document.getElementById('userID');
const regVal = document.getElementById('regiment');
```

Another issue is undefined variables `isValidUID`, `isValidfullname` and `isValidregiment`. You're trying to use them without declaring them first. So at the begining of the script, declare them.

```
var isValidregiment = false;
var isValidUID = false;
var isValidfullname = false;
```

Also, you shouldn't remove the disabled status until all the inputs are valid, so you should be checking with `&&` instead of `||`.

```
if (isValidregimentVal && isValidfullnameVal && isValidUIDVal){
    submit.disabled = false;
} else {
    submit.disabled = true;
}
```

In your `fullnameVal.addEventlistener`, you are only checking `isValidfullnameVal` which isn't enough. You should check all 3 conditions like in code you've written for other checks.

Lastly, set the button to disabled by default otherwise users can submit the form if they didn't type anything or after page reload.

```
<button id="submitbutton" disabled>Submit</button>
```

While we're at it, why not just use a `type=submit` instead of adding an eventlistener to check for submit

```
<button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
```

If you want to fill the table on submit, then use the `submit` event with `preventDefault` and call your `fillTable` function there